# "' object has no attribute 'get' Error

Tags: python, django

Have stuck here for 2 days. Hoping to get some enlightenment. The error code here is "'inputform' object has no attribute 'get'". I highly suspect the error is because of the forms.py. I want to make a dynammic choice field list there.

**Model.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.db import models
from dupont.models import dupont


class input(models.Model):
   ...
    Region=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import input
from anothermodel.models import A   
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import Queue

class inputform(forms.ModelForm):
    regionlist = forms.ChoiceField(label=u'Region',choices=())
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    super(inputform,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.fields['regionlist'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=anothermodel.objects.values('Region').distinct())
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render,render_to_response,get_object_or_404
from inputform.forms import inputform
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def input(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = inputform(request.POST) 
            if form.is_valid(): 
                return HttpResponseRedirect('templates/About') 
    else:
        form = inputform() 

    return render_to_response('inputform.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

**Part of html**

```
<body>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://libs.baidu.com/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.regionlist }}
        {% for region in form.regionlist.choices %}
            <option value="{{ val }}" {% ifequal data.val val %}selected {% endifequal %}>
        {% endfor %}
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from metrics import views
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from inputform.views import input,ifglobal
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^login/',include('login.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^input', 'inputform.views.inputform'),
)
```

**The trackback**

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3 py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
223.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\middleware\clickjacking.py" in process_response
  31.         if response.get('X-Frame-Options', None) is not None:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /input
Exception Value: 'inputform' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Is the indentation correct in your form?

Comment: Theres a few things missing here... Your model form doesn't have a model reference, I can't see what `form.choice_filed` relates to, and could do with the full stack trace

Comment: You need to show your URLs. I doubt that this view is actually getting called.

Comment: Also, your template is completely wrong; the `select` makes no sense at all, and in any case should be completely replaced with just `{{ form.regionlist }}`.

Comment: OK, I have changed as Sayse and Daniel suggest, thanks a lot. But the same alert still hangs there, is there any other missing?

Comment: **Wild guess**: In`if response.get('X-Frame-Options', None) is not None:`, `response` has `no attribute 'get'`. So replace the `get` with something your class `inputform` has defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is indeed in your URLs. Your pattern is pointing at `'inputform.views.inputform'`, ie the form, not the view. It should be `'inputform.views.input'`.

Comment: Génial~! Thanks a lot, Daniel.